# Is a self reference in an object evidence of bad code design

Tags: java, coding-style

I have come across a self reference in some code I was looking at.

Example

```
TestObject selfReference = this;
```

Is there ever a good case in which you would need a self reference in an object? Is this a sign of a bad coding design or style?

EDIT:

This is an example of where if I use `this` it will throw an error, but when using selfReference, it compiles.

```
public class IFrame extends InternalFrame
{
    public IFrame()
    {
         addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) 
            {
                Window.setCurrComponent(this); //compile error
            }
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent evt)
            {
                Window.setCurrComponent(selfReference); //compiles correctly
            }
        });
    }
}

public class InternalFrame extends JInternalFrame
{
    protected InternalFrame selfReference = this;
}

public class Window
{
    InternalFrame currFrame;

    public static void setCurrComponent(InternalFrame iFrame)
    {
        currFrame = iFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the broader context of that code? I can't see why you'd need an alias for `this` (in Java). Now, if that variable can *also* point to something else, depending on some condition, there can be good reasons for *that*. But not one called `selfReference`. Without more context, the question is pretty vague.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why this question has so much activity and interest, yet there are no up-votes.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the interest as well, given that the question is vague and the OP has ignored requests to clarify. People are just in the mood go guess, I guess.

Comment: I was asking around, and I made an edit to what it appears is going on. Also, there have been up votes, just equally as many down votes

Comment: Your new edit doesn't make any sense. The method in the subclass will always be invoked if it's overridden. (The method isn't overloaded in your example)

Comment: @user489041 Yes, that's probably why he had a selfReference. Do however note that you doesn't need it (due to the fact that he can access the outer this)

Comment: @user: Note that in your updated example, you can simply do `Window.setCurrComponent(IFrame.this)`.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there are circumstances in which an *implicit* self-reference may be entirely natural.  Consider, for instance, a circular linked list that currently contains only a single element.

However, having a member variable called `selfReference` doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @jzd: Yes, but that could be the OP changing the name from, say, `head`. ;-)

Comment: If it was a `final` variable, I would agree with you.  Otherwise, this allows the `TestObject` to be this object or another one - initially setting it to this object.  No problem with that.  Of course, the name is goofy.

Comment: @Erick: Yes, precisely!  I have no objection to implicit self-references (i.e. members that just so happen to refer to oneself); that was the crux of my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I'll take a stab on this. I'm guessing that the author of that code didn't know that you can write Classname.this when you want to access "the outer this" from a nested classs.

That is, he created a construct like this:

```
class Executor {
    public void execute(Example example) {

    }
}

public class Example {

    Example selfReference = this;

    class Nested {
        public void method() {
            //Oh, oh, can't do this: 
            //new Executor().execute(this);
            //It gives:
            //The method execute(Example) in the type Executor is not applicable for the arguments (Example.Nested)

            //How the hell do I invoke the executor method from here?
            //lets do something really odd.
            new Executor().execute(selfReference);

            //This is what he should have done
            new Executor().execute(Example.this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your update isn't correct. It's not the same case as in what I explained, and there really is no reason to have an selfReference if you understand that you can access "outer this".

Comment: Gotcha, perhaps it was a poor example. Please see the new one.

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner!

Answer (score 4):

Not necessary.

A perfectly valid case for self-reference is an object that needs some handler. If the object implements that handler interface itself,  the reference to handler is the reference to the very same object. Totally OK, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated code sample, it looks like you're having trouble referencing the outer object from an anonymous inner class. The syntax is:

`OuterClass.this`

In your case:

```
public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) 
{
    Window.setCurrComponent(IFrame.this); //no more compile error
}
```

If you just use `this` alone, you are referencing the `new ComponentAdapter()`.

Thank you for the additional context.

Answer (score 2):

Without more context, the code doesn't do anything useful and is potentially confusing. I don't think it qualifies as "design" or "style".

However more context might show why it is being done.

Comment: I wouldn't make such statements about "code like this" until I inspected the context, but it certainly smells fishy.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that is a sign of bad code:

- everyone knows what `this` means so I can't see the need for a reference called `selfReference`
- unless of course you are planning to change that reference later on to something else -- e.g.

TestObject selfReference = this;
//call some functions on this
selfReference = someOtherObject; //where someOtherObject is an instance of TestObject as well
//call some functions on someOtherObjects

- however, if that is the case and the reference gets re-assigned to something else at some point then it shouldn't be called `selfReference` -- since it can end up not referencing self/this!

Answer (score 2):

I would say a self reference a sign of bad code *in Java*, especially if it's named something like "selfReference," because Java already has a standard self reference named "this".   It's a different story in languages that support closures, since a non-this self reference can keep the "this" object in the scope of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Window.setCurrComponent(this); //compile error
'this' in above statement is not InternalFrame object its ComponentAdapter object, as you are in Anonymous inner class.

Window.setCurrComponent(selfReference); //compiles correctly
above line is correct statement if you want to reference your IFrame class' object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a parser and have a datastructure which contains child elements of the same type then you would need to have member variables of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of times when you want to use a `this`. You should in situations where you need to reference the object it belongs to. I don't see any reason to create an object out of `this` though, a simple `this.attribute` will suffice.

Comment: -1 "create an object out of this" - I don't think you understand what's going on here

Comment: isn't he trying to access his class by assigning it to a variable?

Comment: He's only setting a pointer in this statement.  He's making `this.selfReference = this;`

Comment: Right, what advantage does this give over using `this`? passable to other functions? is `this` not?